# Where should I point my custom domain to environment URL or LoadBalancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I have my custom domain xxx.com.pl I would like to run a service on Elastic Beanstalk. How should I configure my domain. Should I use my Elastic Load Balancer DNS:

```
awseb-e-k-AWSEBLoa-xxx.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

or environment URL:

```
xxx.asdasdasda.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

If I select environment URL I can always create another environment and use swap URLs for recovery. I cannot do this easy way If I select ELB DNS. Probably usage of ELB DNS is faster. Am I right? What is the best practice?

Comment: Are you running your Elastic Beanstalk deployment in a High-Available manner (i.e. across two or more Availability Zones) or are you just using Elastic Beanstalk for its PaaS capabilities?

Comment: I use two AZ eu-central-1a, eu-central-1b. My ELB has Cross-Zone Load Balancing: Enabled.

Comment: The environment URL should simply be a pointer to the ELB.

Comment: and is, but the question is where should I point my domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `CNAME` record to point to the **Load Balancer**: `awseb-e-k-AWSEBLoa-xxx.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

However if you are using Route 53, create an `A` record and use `Alias=Yes` to point to your Elastic Beanstalk app. This type of Alias resolution incurs no charge in Route 53.

Interestingly, [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Adds Support for Amazon Route 53 Aliasing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-support-for-amazon-route-53-aliasing/) suggests that either name is now acceptable.

See:

- [Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Domain Name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html)

Comment: Could someone please elaborate on why you would choose the load balancer over environment url?

Comment: My assumption is that the LB URI can change automatically while the environment URI can only change manually. Hence I would choose the EB URI, not the LB URI.